# How to show label in a loop. For example label 1, label 2 and so on

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

How to show label in a loop.For example label 1, label 2 and so on continuous till the end of the loop.
Here is my code i want to show Experience 1 and Experience 2 and so on through out the loop
till loop ends.

```
 @foreach($employee->experiences as $experince)
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <label for="">Experience</label>
                                </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6"><b>Company:</b></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">{{ ucfirst($experince->company) }}</div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6"><b>Degree :</b></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">{{ ucfirst($employee->degree) }}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `$loop->iteration`  ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable

```php
@foreach($employee->experiences $experince)
<div class="card-header">
    <label for="">Experience {{ $loop->iteration }}</label>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-6"><b>Company:</b></div>
                <div class="col-md-6">{{ ucfirst($experince->company) }}</div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-6"><b>Degree :</b></div>
                <div class="col-md-6">{{ ucfirst($employee->degree) }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: this solution worked but the problem is that it show experience o and experience 1 i want to show experience 1 and then so on.

Comment: just solved this problem by using $loop and  $loop->iteration

Answer (score 1):

In blade template there is a `$loop` variable:

```
$loop->index
```

will print the current index, starting from 0

```
$loop->iteration
```

will instead start from 1

The variable is available inside a `@foreach`:

```
 @foreach($employee->experiences as $experince)
   {{ $loop->iteration }}
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `it` variable as iteration and increment it each iterations

```
@php
$it = 1;
@endphp
@foreach($employee->experiences as $experince)
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <label for="">Experience</label>
                                </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6"><b>Label:{{ $it }}</b></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6"><b>Company:</b></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">{{ ucfirst($experince->company) }}</div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6"><b>Degree :</b></div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">{{ ucfirst($employee->degree) }}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @php
                              $it += 1;
                            @endphp
                            @endforeach
```